# how to avoid the # in the address bar of the browser after selecting the menu item

Tags: jquery, html

I have a menubar. Each item on the menubar is a hyperlink:

```
  <a href="#" title="item1">
```

Based on the menu selection, I am displaying a few divs and hiding the remaining divs. Everything works fine. If I click on the menu item the results are displaying on the same page that is fine but on the browser address bar `#` symbol is displaying like `localhost/abc#` which is causing to activate the Browser Back( <-- ) button which may give a wrong a assumption to user that they can click on the back button on the browser.

**IS there a way to avoid displaying the `#` in the address bar?**

I am using the `return false;` statment in the event handling function to disable the href link.

Comment: Your return false in the event handler should be enough to stop the # appearing in the address bar; check that your event handler isn't exiting prematurely.

Comment: Kelvin and Blaze, thanks a lot for your response, I corrected the JS code, I placed the return statment in wrong place now I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you end the event handler with `return false` as you say it will not appear in your address bar. Basically there's something not going quite as it should between the event handler being called and `return false` (since it doesn't return). Make sure that your JavaScript is error free.

Comment: Karl, thanks a lot for your response, I corrected the JS code, I placed the return statment in wrong place now I corrected it.

Answer (score 6):

***Is there a way to avoid displaying the # in the address bar?***

Yes, you can avoid `#` by changing the

```
<a href="#" title="item1">
```

to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="item1">
```

**Why is it displaying #?** (from MDN)

> **href**
>   - This is the single required attribute for anchors defining a hypertext source link. It indicates the link target, either a URL or a URL fragment. A URL fragment is a name preceded by **a hash mark (#), which specifies an internal target location (an ID) within the current document.** URLs are not restricted to Web (HTTP)-based documents. URLs might use any protocol supported by the browser. For example, file, ftp, and mailto work in most user agents.

Comment: Vega, thanks a lot for your response, I corrected the JS code, I placed the return statment in wrong place now I corrected it.  I verified once again by replacing # with javascript:void(0) it's also working, thanks for sharing this.